# is it possible to implement c4.5 algorithm in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, cart-analysis, c4.5

I've read in the documentation that sklearn uses CART algorithm for trees.

Are there specific attributes to change so that it becomes similar to a c4.5 implementation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CART and C4.5 are somehow similar algorithms, but there are fundamental differences which won't let you tweak sklearn's implementation to get a C4.5 without a lot of work.

C4.5 uses rule sets to decide where to split the data, whereas CART merely uses a numerical splitting criterion.

You can take a look at [this](https://github.com/geerk/C45algorithm) implementation of C4.5